# Is there any common thread pool executor in C++ for std::packaged_task?

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

In C++17, I find no executor other than just creating a `std::thread` to execute a `std::packed_task` and then fetch its result.

I found some [demos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174684/c-threadpool-executor-implementation) of executors for `std::packed_task`. However this is just a demo without any optimization.

However, I wonder if there are some mature implementation of thread pool that can execute a `std::packed_task`?

Comment: In C++ 17, no not yet. But I also had to write my a threadpool from scratch (can't share, its company work). The part that needed most attention was to decide how to stop the threadpool (with work still running). And in general  I prefer to use std::async over std::thread.

Comment: @PepijnKramer How to execute a `packaged_task` by `async`?

Comment: capture it in a lambda and call its operator().  but packaged task is a template so either you must only allow void functions to be called or you need some base interface for queing. Also make sure you guarantee the lifetime of the packaged task (e.g. make a shared_ptr to it so it is always safe to pass to a background thread even when created from a function call).

Comment: If you figure out, please post.

Comment: @trozzel I implemented according to Pepijn Kramer's comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Pepijn Kramer's comment, I have the following implementation.

```
#include "thread_pool.h"
#include <future>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    int total = 10;
    int thread_size = 4;
    // From thread_pool.h
    Nuke::ThreadExecutor pool(thread_size);

    std::vector<std::future<int>> futs;
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        using P = std::packaged_task<int()>;
        std::shared_ptr<P> task = std::make_shared<P>([i]() {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms);
            return i;
        });
        futs.emplace_back(task->get_future());
        pool.add_task([task]() { (*task)(); });
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", futs[i].get());
    }
}
```

I used [my implementation](https://github.com/CalvinNeo/Nuke/blob/master/src/thread_pool.h) of a task queue, which only handles `std::function<void()>`.

By wrapping my `std::packaged_task<int()>` into `std::function<void()>`, I can reuse my task queue.